# How to handle global variables to be tha same for all users in PHP?

Tags: php, server, multiplayer

I want to create simple multiplayer game with php using global variables that will be shared among all users, without using sockets.

I tried write php server that have on global variable called "connections" and code to handle GET request with url parameter that called "myName".
when the user send the GET request to the php server, "connections" is incremented and sent back to the user as the GET response.

```
<?php
    $connections = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['myName'])) {
        $connections = $connections+ 1;
        echo json_encode($connections);
        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
        <form action="Test/testServer.php">
            <input type="text" name="myName">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to php and perhaps i missing something about how php server is actually work. I expected the "connections" to be the number of connected users that send GET request along all the "server life".

Comment: This is not how PHP works. For persisting and sharing data, you usually use a Mysql database with a database layer like `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: PHP is server side, it executes then the state is forgot. Consider using a method of storing the data.

Comment: @Jaquarh - What do you mean by "method of storing the data"?  Do you mean something like DB?
Do you have some example from which i can understand how to do this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a Server side language, once the program is executed, the state of everything is forgot. Therefore, in the next request, unless stored in cache, it will not exist.

However, you can use the likes of a Database to store data. You can connect to your Database like so:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
));
```

To execute, you can use Prepared statements.

```
// (new PDO) is your pre-instanced PDO
$stmt = (new PDO)->Prepare('SELECT id FROM test WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array('foo@bar.com'));
$stmt->fetch(); // Array ( 'id' => (int) 1 )
```

In your case, you would need to set up a Database to register connections. When a new player joins, for a utter basic (no security) example, you could store his ID.

```
session_start();
// new PDO is your pre-instanced PDO
$con = new PDO;
$con->Prepare('INSERT INTO players (username) VALUES (?)')->execute(array('foo'));
$_SESSION['player.id.insecure'] = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Then, what you are trying to achieve all comes down to your infrastructure. You can read more on [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) here.

Comment: Hi, first thank you for the explanation. It is definitely clearer now. But, does DB is good to store data of real time multiplayer game? I want the server to "tell" to all users who is the winner for example. I heard about something called "websockets" but i don't really found good tutorial to start with and i thought i can avoid it in another way.

Comment: Websockets doesn't keep the Server alive, it is just a constant stream of data. I'm not 100% sure if PHP has NIO capability, so data will need to be stored as I'm aware, but worth researching. The reason you'd use sockets is to keep the client alive in this case, so every n seconds, the server knows what client is still connected. Thus, player 1 can communicate to the server, and pass the data to player 2. This would happen at different request intervals, IE: `/server/incomming` and `/server/outgoing` requests. The Sockets would constantly stream these two requests.

Comment: Yes, sockets is probably what i need.                        Thank you very much it clearer now.